# network request failed react native on android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

When I create a brand new project using react-native init and put a fetch in the render method to the public facebook demo movie API, it throws a Network Request Failed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC8gW.jpg)

Comment: Can I expo link?

Comment: I have encountered this issue several times, and its not the code its emulator's fault (in my case). Try running your app in a real device